# Edit CSS without class

Tags: html, css, wordpress, select, selector

I have a Wordpress-Website and want to edit the css of a specific site (generated from a plugin).
The problem is, I want to remove (`display: none`) a header (h2). But the h2 doesn't have a class (and because it isn't the only h2, I cannot `display: none` all the h2), so I cant select it with CSS. **Is there a way to select something without a class?**

Comment: what is the code generated by the plugin, where about does that h2 stands in the structure of your page, ... ? There is possibilities but no ways to guess how you should write your selector to match a single element of your DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed! find an element above it in the DOM which you CAN select, like a container with a classname, and use a selector. For example, if you have:

```
<div className="section12">
<h2>Stuff</h2>
</div>
```

Then use something like:

```
.section12 h2 { display: block; }
```

However, if you are using something like Elementor on your site, then you can just remove the H2 in some other way, or even add a class name to it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But what if there are more (for example) h2 in the container etc. and I only want to select that one h2?

Comment: BTW in my case this worked, but am still curious if there is a way ;D

Comment: Curiosity is great! ^^ The best thing is to give the element an identifier, but if you have multiple appearances of the same structure and only want to edit one, then you have to be particular.

Lets say you have a gallery which is a div containing images. And you want to edit the last, first, or nth.

Then you can use .gallery:first-child {} or even be more specific. There are also selectors to affect the first element of a particular type inside of a container etc. For example, the 1st h2 :-)

For more info, look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with selectors like nth-child() ...

For example, suppose you want to make the second h2 tag red. This solution will be useful when there is no class name.

```css
h2:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>hello</h2>
<h2>hello</h2>
<h2>hello</h2>
<h2>hello</h2>
<h2>hello</h2>
```

Comment: That also was what I was looking for! Thank you very much! :)